# Dynamically updating count in PHP?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm not sure how to really word this. I've been getting into PHP CLI lately, and I wanted to make like a dynamic counter. For example, it starts with echoing `Count: 0` and then as the count increases (or decreases) the number changes as the program advances.

I hope you can understand what I mean. If you do, any idea on if its possible, and if so, how to do it?

Comment: I'm afraid it's a bit too vague. Perhaps try to give some example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you question, you don't wan't to repeatedly echo "Count: N", but you want it to remain on the screen and that only the number changes.
For this you must use the PHP extension Ncurses - https://www.php.net/ncurses
It's basically a wrapper for the Ncurses terminal control library. It's quite powerful but not so easy to learn.

Comment: +1 For mentioning ncurses in combination with PHP, people forget it can handle CLI applications.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a file somewhere in a directory like:

```
/files/counter.txt
```

Start it with a single number 0,
then every time you want to change it, read the file in
and update it. Since the only content in the file
is a number, just increment it.